# How to defeat input field formatting?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgraded, and to my horror, all DATE fields now has fancy widgetry for data entry.

I often enter a bunch of records with the same dates. I would enter (for example) "2014-01-04", select the entire field, copy it, then paste it into the same field of other records with a single keystroke.

The new "improved" widgetry requires multiple mouse clicks or tabbing through yyyy, mm, and dd subfields.

How can I do "raw" data entry of such fields?

UPDATE: Per Marc's comment, I tried it on Firefox and Safari, and it works as desired!

Here are screen dumps from Firefox, Safari and Chrome, showing the difference. First, Safari, showing the free-text date field with the pastebuffer pasted in.:

[image: Safari, showing the free-text date field with the pastebuffer pasted in.]

Next, Firefox, showing the free-text date field with the pastebuffer pasted in:

[image: Firefox, showing the free-text date field with the pastebuffer pasted in.]

Finally, Chrome, showing the three-field widget, which does not change when pasted into.

[image: Chrome, showing the three-field widget, which does not change when pasted into.]

Comment: I just discovered the little circle-x button that allows raw DATE data entry. But I still want to do direct entry by default, as I am in the habit of never touching the mouse for most data entry. It appears that the "circle-x" button requires a mouse click.

Comment: Under Firefox, with phpMyAdmin version 4.1.3 and a DATE column, I have no problem selecting a date "2014-01-04", copy, tab to the next row and paste it. I did not use the calendar wizard with this operation.

Comment: No, "circle-x" simply resets the field -- still has a date picker in it. Grepped through the theme directory for "datepicker" and attempted to make a new theme without the datepicker, using the on-line info for making a new theme. Didn't work...

Comment: Out of frustration, backed out 4.1.3 and returned to 4.0.8 -- YAY! NO DATE PICKER! Entered ~100 records with the same date... can't believe no one else has such a work flow and hasn't complained...

Comment: @Marc Delisle, I was using Chrome, and saw no way to do as you suggest. I'll try it in Firefox. But from crawling through the code, there certainly seems to be a jquery date picker widget embedded in DATE fields.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I opened a bug ticket: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4218/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Seems to be an issue with Chrome, if anything.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, perhaps I misunderstand, but I got here via a link on the phpMyAdmin site as a place to post support issues, which is what I did. It was only through working with Marc's constructive comments that it came to be a Chrome issue.

Comment: @Jan OK, my mistake. However, do note that Stack Overflow is not for reporting bugs with PMA - if something is not working as expected you should submit a bug report (as you have now done).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, I don't feel I've been heard.

I followed a link from the phpMyAdmin site for "support." And I got it. The system appears to have worked.

I don't understand your persistent gripe. Have I detracted from the Stack Overflow experience in some way? I just checked the submission guidelines, and I don't believe I've violated them. "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." And so I did.

Have I wronged you in some way?

Comment: @Jan no need to be indignant, I'm just trying to help :) SO is for programming questions, and yes they are pretty strict about what is allowed.